# No sound on ASUS Transformer T100HA

Tags: sound, alsa, asus

So after having an Ubuntu 20.04 fresh install into the ASUS Transformer T100HA, I've faced a no-sound issue. The system recognized the following outputs:

- Multichannel
- Internal audio

But no sound with any output

Answer (score 3):

So the solution was actually very easy:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall alsa-ucm-conf

echo "options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=2" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

[Reference: github sof project issue](https://github.com/thesofproject/sof/issues/3868)